# JavaScript Table Pagination Rendering JSON Data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, rendering

I'm fetching data in JSON format from a URL and rendering it to a table, but I need to show only 10 rows per page and I am not sure how to do it

Here is the code to render the data:

```
const url = "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/bstech-ux/e717b74dbd7cc95a8429eadc83a5c882/raw/ca85214d461ef93c316a47a6770c4b9ba678a6b3/movies.json";
    // Get JSON Data and Loop Through Each Object in the Array
    $.getJSON(url, (data) => {
        // parsePaginationData(data);
        let movie_data = "";
        // Append Data to movie_data Variable
        $.each(data, (key, value) => {
            movie_data += 
            `<tr>
                <td scope="row">${value.id}</td>
                <td>${value.title}</td>
                <td>${value.director}</td>
                <td>${value.distributor}</td>
                <td class="rating">${value.imdb_rating}</td>
                <td class="votes">${value.imdb_votes}</td>
                <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button></td>
            </tr>`;
        });

        $('#movies').append(movie_data);

    });
```

Comment: You can [split the array in to chunks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8495740/519413) and then traverse forwards/backwards through that as needed. Also note that githubusercontent isn't intended as a CDN, so I'd suggest using a local copy of that file.

Comment: use datatable its one liner.

Comment: I am not supposed to use a database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store you data in an array.

The fuunction `displayMovie` will take a page parameter (default 1) and display movies depends on wich page you want.

To know how many page there are, use [Math.ceil](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Math/ceil). With this number you can append as many as "pagination button" you need.

```js
let movies = [];
const url = "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/bstech-ux/e717b74dbd7cc95a8429eadc83a5c882/raw/ca85214d461ef93c316a47a6770c4b9ba678a6b3/movies.json";
    // Get JSON Data and Loop Through Each Object in the Array
    $.getJSON(url, (data) => {
        movies = data;
        displayMovies();
        setPages();
    });
    
    function displayMovies(page = 1){
       let movie_data = "";
       let max = page*10;
       let min = max-10;
        // Append Data to movie_data Variable
        for(let i = min; i < max; i++){
          let movie = movies[i];
           if(movie){
            movie_data += 
            `<tr>
                <td scope="row">${movie.id}</td>
                <td>${movie.title}</td>
                <td>${movie.director}</td>
                <td>${movie.distributor}</td>
                <td class="rating">${movie.imdb_rating}</td>
                <td class="votes">${movie.imdb_votes}</td>
                <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button></td>
            </tr>`;
           }else{
            break;
           }
        }
       

        $('#movies').html(movie_data);
    }
    
    
    function setPages(){
      let nbPages = Math.ceil(movies.length/10);
      let pages = "";
      for(let i = 1; i <= nbPages; i++){
       pages+='<button type="button" onClick="displayMovies('+i+')">Page '+i+'</button>'
      }
       $('#pages').append(pages);
     
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="movies"></div>
<div id="pages"></div>
```

Comment: All good except when I click on "pagination button" I get an error

"(index):1 Uncaught ReferenceError: displayMovies is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick ((index):1)"

Comment: There must be a typo in your code. As you can see the code i post works fine. Verify were your defined your `displayMovies`function. If the answer is good for you, please park it as answered

Comment: Link to the code: https://jsfiddle.net/natefr0st/L5zujy6k/3/

I can't find the mistake : /

Comment: Thanks a lot! You are a savior !